# Other ways to add a parameter to initComponents [java-netbeans]

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, parameter-passing

I have a huge problem with my GUI java project in netbeans.
It is well-known that the code compiled by netbeans is read-only and I need an other way to add a parameter to the initComponents method, besides calling a myInitComponents method, identical to initComponents, and calling it in the constructor.
Now I have this:

```
public class MainFrame {

    public MainFrame() {
       DefaultStyledDocument doc = new DefaultStyledDocument();
       myInitComponents(doc);
    }

    myInitComponents (DefaultStyledDocument doc) {
       //components
       textModel = new javax.swing.JTextPane(doc);
       //components
    }

    initComponents () {
      //components
    }
```

In this way it works, but every time I change something within the frame, I have to copy and pase all the new code of initComponents inside myInitComponent.
Moreover, this is a very awful  way to do that. 
Is there any other way to add that parameter? 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can take a look at my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I fixed this in a very simple way. I inserted all the code needed for the *DefaultStyleDocument* in the *initComponents()* method by clicking on **customize code** and adding it as **pre-creation** code.

```
public class MainFrame {

    public MainFrame() {

       myInitComponents();
    }

  //delete the myInitComponents() method

    initComponents () {
   //code useful for the DefaultStyledDocument..
    DefaultStyledDocument doc = new DefaultStyledDocument();
      //components
      textModel = new javax.swing.JTextPane(doc);
    }
```

Hope this could be useful to somebody.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a parameter to the MainFrame constructor, place it in a field, use custom creation code in the properties table of the GUI builder.

There a couple of free code places to insert in the code of initComponents. Create custom code is such a place;

```
private final DefaultStyledDocument doc = new DefaultStyledDocument();
```

And in "custom creation code:"

```
new JTextPane(doc)
```

Which can also be used for custom panels etcetera.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a huge problem with my GUI java project in netbeans. It is well-known that the code compiled by netbeans is read-only and I need an other way to add a parameter to the initComponents method, besides calling a myInitComponents method, identical to initComponents, and calling it in the constructor

I think you are probably confused between using **constructors** for initializations and **setters** for accessing values.

This is as good as asking: if you have a class with attributes like a, b & c, how to create a setter which set all attributes. This is something you should avoid. You could just create an individual setter and getter for each property instead of trying to use an `init` to set ***all*** attributes.

**You should be doing this:**

```
class MyClass
{
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;

    public MyClass(){
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        a = 100;
        b = 200;
        c = 300;
    }

    public int getA(){return a;}  
    public int getB(){return b;}
    public int getC(){return c;}

    public void setA(int a){this.a = a;}
    public void setB(int b){this.a = b;}
    public void setC(int c){this.a = c;}
}
```

**instead of this:**

```
class MyClass
{
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;

    public MyClass(){
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        a = 100;
        b = 200;
        c = 300;
    }

    public void myInit(int a, int b, int c){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

> this is a very awful way to do that. Is there any other way to add that parameter?

So you asked, if you have one more attribute, say `int d`. How should I add it to the parameter list of `myInit()`. So you already start to see the problem with this approach for your class design.

If possible, we try to achieve ***low coupling*** and ***high cohesion*** in our design. When you dump various unrelated attributes within a single method, you are steering towards low cohesion (a method which is not performing a very specific task).

If you try to use a single method like `myInit()` and use it as a setter to set multiple fields, it can cause a number of problems.

- What if the user only wants to set a specific attribute, and not the rest?

---

So to answer your question, use individual setters for each attribute, unless the attributes are closely related for example:

```
setLocation(int x, int y);
setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height);
```